# preload images on the Image Thumbnail Viewer

Tags: javascript, html

how can preload images on the Image Thumbnail Viewer when the page load.

I 
had set the preload:yes, but the picture doesn't preload automatically. anyone know how to fix it?

```
rev="targetdiv:loadarea, preload:yes"
```

here is the link ot my page: http://tianwang.web44.net/Untitled-1.html

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this between your head tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.images){
  preload_image_object = new Image();
  // list all image urls here:
  image_url = new Array();
  image_url[0] = "http://mydomain.com/image0.gif";
  image_url[1] = "http://mydomain.com/image1.gif";
  image_url[2] = "http://mydomain.com/image2.gif";
  image_url[3] = "http://mydomain.com/image3.gif";

   var i = 0;
   for(i=0; i<=3; i++) 
     preload_image_object.src = image_url[i];
}
</script>
```

More details and an explanation here:
http://elouai.com/javascript-preload-images.php

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks @j0k. I've made an edit above to include a full answer.